# Extract the logical conditions from TXT file and apply them to a data in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to use R to extract some operational condition (i.e. X>10) found in txt file and apply them to attached data in R. So, I attached a data to R in csv format of row=40 and column=4 (X1,X2,X3,X4).

```
dat1=readLines("Patterns Interpreted.txt")
dat1
 [1] "-------------------------" "  Class 1 Vs. Class 0"     "-------------------------"
 [4] "Pattern  1"                "X4  Less Than  141.5"      ""                         
 [7] "-------------------------" "  Class 0 Vs. Class 1"     "-------------------------"
[10] "Pattern  1"                "X4  Greater Than   141.5"  ""                         

dat2<-read.csv("LR.csv")
dat2
     X1    X2    X3  X4   X5  X6    Y
1  2140 20640 30250 205 1732  99 4540
2  2016 20280 30010 195 1697 100 4315
3  1905 19860 29780 184 1662  97 4095

# For replacement in txt file
tx2  <- gsub(pattern = "  Less Than  ", replace = "<", x = dat1)
tx22 <- gsub(pattern = "  Greater Than   ", replace = ">", x = tx2)
tx22
 [1] "-------------------------" "  Class 1 Vs. Class 0"     "-------------------------"
 [4] "Pattern  1"                "X4<141.5"                  ""                         
 [7] "-------------------------" "  Class 0 Vs. Class 1"     "-------------------------"
[10] "Pattern  1"                "X4>141.5"                  ""
```

Refer to txt there is condition for each pattern. I need to extract these conditions automatically as logical conditions. In other words, if I have `X4=120` which satisfy the first condition let say a new variable `p=0` while does not satisfy the second condition so `p=1`.

How to do this in R?

Comment: (1) Please, one question at a time: first, try and if-needed ask about parsing that text file; then, once that is working, ask a different question about how to apply that in a good way to columns of a frame. (2) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: Is it clear now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` with `str2lang` to succeed that.

```
x<-5
str_cond<-"x<3"
condition<-str2lang(str_cond)
eval(condition) #prints FALSE
```

For your example split your string condition to right and left part and use the left part as string index name to your dat1 to get the column you want.

```
str_cond<-"X4<141.5"
cond_parts<-strplit(str_cond,"<")[[1]] # split string
assign(cond_parts[1],dat1[,cond_parts[1]]) # create variable with name the left part and assign the column
condition<-str2lang(str_cond) # create language condition
eval(condition) # execute the language condition
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another question, How could I get automatically the lines between each string "Pattern"? it should be noted that there is no pattern 3 to get the kines between (pattern 2 and 3).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean... You want to do what with these lines?